# Writing raster field values into attribute table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1

Is it possible to use ArcPy (10 or 10.1 ) to write raster field types into a featureclass in either ArcSDE or a file geodatabase?.

I am hoping to use arcpy as means of automating the process of adding rasters as an attribute to a feature class.

Comment: Do you mean add raster name to feature class field?  I'm not sure what you mean by "raster field types" and "adding rasters as an attribute".

Comment: when adding a field to a featureclass you need to choose what type that field is, one of the options is type Raster meaning that you can store a raster as an attribute of a feature.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is currently possible to update fields of type raster with arcpy as [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/UpdateCursor/018w00000014000000/) and the [Calculate Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) tool do not support raster fields.

You could consider using [attachments](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Attachments_toolset/00170000015m000000/) as an alternative approach.